# State not being lifted in React project because of TypeError:

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm following two React courses on the "lifting state up" portion of State management and I'm having issues with the "lifting state up" concept on React and they are rejecting my code because of this error: ***"Form.jsx:58 Uncaught TypeError: props.onSaveStudioData is not a function"*** As a result, the addition of a New Studio from the form submission isn't being brought to the App component and just gets stuck on this error.

Not sure why, I've already tried the following:

1. Double checking the parent and sibling components (NewStudio and
   App) to see if there were any typos and there were indeed none.
2. Making the Form function have multiple states instead of one state
   configuration, but it still renders the problem.
3. Changing the
   parameter on the Form function component to "props", but it creates
   a separate error.

Here's the code of my Form component. It looks like the inputs were correctly upon checking. What could be causing the type error?

```
export default function Form( props ) {
  const manilaCities = ["Bulacan", "Caloocan", "Navotas", "Pasig", "Parañaque", "Quezon City", "San Juan", "Taguig"];


  const [inputtedTitle, setTitle] = useState('')
  const [inputtedAddress, setAddress] = useState('')
  const [inputtedCity, setCity] = useState('')

  const titleChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setTitle(event.target.value);
};

const addressChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setAddress(event.target.value);
}

const cityChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setCity(event.target.value);
};

  const submitText = (event) => { 

    event.preventDefault();
    
    // setTitle(event.target.value);
    // setAddress(event.target.value);
    // setCity(event.target.value);
    
    const studioData = {
      name: inputtedTitle,
      address: inputtedAddress,
      city: inputtedCity
    }

    props.onSaveStudioData(studioData);
    setTitle('');
    setAddress('');
    setCity('');
    

  }

  const cityOption = manilaCities.map((city, index) => <option key={index} value={city}> {city} </option>)
  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={submitText} className={`bg-sky-500 flex flex-col p-8 m-12 text-center rounded-2xl ${props.isVisible ? "" : "hidden"} `}>
        <label htmlFor="">Studio Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="studio-name" value={inputtedTitle} onChange={titleChangeHandler} />
        <label htmlFor="">Address </label>
        <input type="text" name="Hey" value={inputtedAddress} onChange={addressChangeHandler} />
        <label htmlFor=""> City </label>
        <select value={inputtedCity} onChange={cityChangeHandler} >
          {cityOption}
        </select>
        <label htmlFor=""> Studio Image </label>
        <span className="m-1"><input type="file" name="Hey" id="" /></span>
        <span className="inline-block"><button type="submit" className="rounded-full bg-sky-50 py-2 px-4 m-1">Add Studio</button></span>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

As suggested, here's the code of other two components:

NewStudio (sibling):

```
import Form from '../Form';    
export default function NewStudio(props) {
    const saveStudioDataHandler = (enteredStudioData) => {
        const studioData = {
            ...enteredStudioData,
            id: Math.random().toString()
        };
       props.onAddStudio(studioData);
    }

    return (
    <div>
        <Form onSaveStudioData = {saveStudioDataHandler} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

App (parent)

```
import Form from './components/Form';
import StudioList from './components/Studios/StudioList'
import { useState } from 'react';
import NewStudio from './components/Studios/NewStudio';


export default function App() {
  const [isFormVisible, setIsFormVisible] = useState(false);
  const toggleFormVisibility = () => {
    setIsFormVisible(!isFormVisible);
  }

  const addStudioHandler = (studio) => {
    console.log('In App.js')
    console.log(studio);
  }


  return (
    <div>
      <Nav toggleForm={toggleFormVisibility}/>
      <NewStudio onAddStudio={addStudioHandler}/>
      <Hero/>
      <Form isVisible={isFormVisible} />
      <StudioList/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Edit: Removed unnecessary comments on each of the change handler events.

Comment: Where do you use the `<Form />` component? The error sounds like you're not passing it a valid `onSaveStudioData` prop.

Comment: I use it on both the App and NewStudio component.

Comment: It's called on the NewStudio component like this <Form onSaveStudioData = {saveStudioDataHandler} />

Comment: Thanks for editing, I also see that you're using it in the App component: `<Form isVisible={isFormVisible} />`, this would be causing the error to appear as this form isn't being passed a `onSaveStudioData` prop.

Comment: Thank you so much! Incredibly careless of me (as usual). I'm going to make it a point to bring all possible states up.

Answer (score -1):

It looks to me that you do not pass the right variable as a prop

Try following code, where you are using your `<Form>` Component

```
<Form onSaveStudioData={onSaveStudioData} />
```

where onSaveStudioData should be a function, because you are using it like that in your component.

For better help you should also post more context, in this case the parent component would be very helpful

Edit after Question was updated:

Your parent uses the `<Form>` component but never passes a prop called onSaveStudioData. But I also see another problem. I think you want to hide your form in the parent with the isVisible prop, but this doesnt do anything other than just passing a boolean down to the form. If you want to hide your Form component you should consider conditional rendering in your App.js, like

```
export default function App() {
  const [isFormVisible, setIsFormVisible] = useState(false);
  const toggleFormVisibility = () => {
    setIsFormVisible(!isFormVisible);
  }

  const addStudioHandler = (studio) => {
    console.log('In App.js')
    console.log(studio);
  }

  function renderForm() {
    if (isFormVisible()) return <Form onSaveStudioData={addStudioHandler } />
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Nav toggleForm={toggleFormVisibility}/>
      <NewStudio onAddStudio={addStudioHandler}/>
      <Hero/>
      {renderForm()}
      <StudioList/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your solution worked. For the conditional rendering fix you mentioned, it seems to be working with my original code, but I will still consider your solution as an alternate method.

Comment: ah you know, nevermind. i just double checked. in your form you use `props.isVisible ? "" : "hidden` in the style attribute. i didn't see that the first time.
If you liked my solution and ended up using it maybe consider accepting this answer